# Is 'real crop' a possibility?

Tags: image-transforms, image

Ok, this is the first time I need this, but here's my question:

If *crop* is selected for a transition, what you get is a *scaleAndCrop*. Is there a way to do a 'real' crop, so no resizing before cropping?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, no.

It is on our list to open us the asset transformation pipeline so that plugins can add new transforms that go beyond what is available out of the box in Craft, though.