# Can I "circle crop" an image asset?

Tags: assets, image-transforms

Is it possible for me to create an image transformation that generates a cirle cropped thumbnail?

Just like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer: No.
However, as [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2476/is-real-crop-a-possibility) states, it will be possible to do this in the future.

Just as a tip, I know it doesn't answer your question: it's an effect you can easily achieve with CSS, by rounding the corners to 50%.

Comment: Yeah. I just wanted it to be bulletproof. Thanks :)

Comment: @naboovalley As long as the background is just a solid color, you don't have to do anything complex like CSS masking etc – just use `border-radius` and `overflow: hidden`, which should be bulletproof at this point :)

Comment: Yes. That's the best solution without touching the image.